# Help colorizing layer defined by image mask/bounds and overlaying the image on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-graphics

I am currently experimenting with an avatar creation iOS app for a client, where at some point the user should have the option of changing the color of an item.

The client provides the gallery items to be colorized in .png format with different alpha/opacity values as usual, to effectively produce the shades. The correct final result of the item colorization however is not masking the image and applying a color blend since transparent areas remain as is, but rather "fill" the background area enclosed by the item's "outer stroke" and then redraw the image on top of it so the shades apply on the new color.

Here's what I've achieved:

```
UIImage *image =  item.image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -area.size.height);

CGContextSaveGState(context);

// This applies the colorization only on the image mask 
//CGContextClipToMask(context, area, image.CGImage);

[[UIColor redColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(context, area);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextDrawImage(context, area, image.CGImage);

UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

item.image = coloredImg;
```

which produces the following result.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1237004/Screen%20shot%202011-07-15%20at%207.53.50%20%CE%BC.%CE%BC..png

This is basically close to what I really want to achieve, except the red area expanding outside the pants.

So how's possible to eliminate that part? I was thinking of maybe reducing the alpha value to the area NOT defined by the image mask or something like that but couldn't come close to a solution.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

NOTE: the item showing in the screenshot is part of the WeeMee avatar creation application, not used in our app but rather part of my experiments, and all rights belong to it's respective owners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to set up a clipping path, and instruct CG to fill only inside the inside area. If you're already drawing the path that define the pants, this should be trivial for you.

See this tutorial:
[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2106/core-graphics-101-arcs-and-paths)

Updated in response to comments:

[Masking an image](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html)

Comment: I don't think that this somehow solves my problem. You see, I don't actually draw any path for the pants by myself but I rather use the pants' .png to create an image mask. I can't see any direct way of creating a clipping path out of the items I have, unless you have another suggestion. thanx

Comment: Can you give me an example of a source image (without the color applied to it?) Perhaps you can use a CG mask to perform the clipping instead if you have clearly defined regions for the pants.

Comment: This is the same image without the color applied (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1237004/bottoms_005_outline_gM%402x.png). The regions of the pants are clearly defined but if you mask the image and colorize it, you don't get the exact result I want. You see the end result I want is like the sshot in my question without red expanding out of the pants region. thanx